# how to make a function return every possible values

Tags: python, return, lxml

So I am using writing this method, which work fine in term of looking up number but it only return last value. is there a way to  make it so it return all the values after each run. 
here is my code:

```
def searchPFAM():

    fileAddress = '/Volumes/interpro/data/Q14591.txt'
    start = None
    end = None
    with open(fileAddress,'rb') as f:
        root = etree.parse(f)
        for lcn in root.xpath("/protein/match[@dbname='PFAM']/lcn"):#find dbname =PFAM
            start = int(lcn.get("start"))#if it is PFAM then look for start value
            end = int(lcn.get("end"))#if it is PFAM then also look for end value
            print start, end
        return start, end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something similar to this?

```
def do_something(fname):
    with open(fname,'rb') as f:
        root = etree.parse(f)
        for lcn in root.xpath("/protein/match[@dbname='PFAM']/lcn"):#find dbname =PFAM
            # Make slightly more robust
            try:
                start = int(lcn.get("start"))#if it is PFAM then look for start value
                end = int(lcn.get("end"))#if it is PFAM then also look for end value
                yield start, end
            except (TypeError , ValueError) as e:
                pass # start/end aren't usable as numbers decide what to do here...

for start, end in do_something():
    do_something_else(start, end)
```

Comment: will i be able to pass these value on another method.. or do i have to combine another method so i have for loop in between two of my method

Comment: @ChadD yes you can, use these values with some other functions.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary  would i just pass start and end as parameter or i need to do something because what i had before is start, end = searchPFAM() would this work?

Comment: I think the for loop used by jon clements is perfectly ok.
`for start, end in do_something():
    do_something_else(start, end)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13805/discussion-between-chad-d-and-ashwini-chaudhary)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of tuples of start and end and just return the list at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your function to create and return a list of start,end tuples:

```
def searchPFAM():
    fileAddress = '/Volumes/interpro/data/Q14591.txt'
    start = None
    end = None
    result = []
    with open(fileAddress,'rb') as f:
        root = etree.parse(f)
        for lcn in root.xpath("/protein/match[@dbname='PFAM']/lcn"):#find dbname =PFAM
            start = int(lcn.get("start"))#if it is PFAM then look for start value
            end = int(lcn.get("end"))#if it is PFAM then also look for end value
            print start, end
        result.append((start, end))
    return result
```

A little less readable, but more compact and efficient way to write it would be to use what is knowm as a "list comprehension" would be like this:

```
def searchPFAM():
    fileAddress = '/Volumes/interpro/data/Q14591.txt'
    start = None
    end = None
    with open(fileAddress,'rb') as f:
        root = etree.parse(f)
        result = [(int(lcn.get("start")), int(lcn.get("end"))) 
                     for lcn in root.xpath("/protein/match[@dbname='PFAM']/lcn")]
    return result
```

Afterwards you can process the returned list like this:

```
for start,end in result:
   ... # do something with pair of int values
```

or

```
for i in xrange(len(result)):
   start,end = result[i][0],result[i][1]
   ... # do something with pair of int values
```

Comment: if i have a list then, will i be able to pass start and end values as int or do i need to make another method to read it before i can pass them

Comment: @ChadD: You can extract each tuple from the list and then each integer of that in a `for` loop. Something like `for start,end in result: ...`. You can also directly access any one of them in the list returned with something like `result[n][0]` and `result[n][1]` for the start and end values of n'th one.